# Symfony 4 : The file was found but the class was not in it

Tags: symfony, routes, composer-php, symfony4, autoloader

this problem has been asked a lot but none of the answer could help me. 
I'm doing a symfony 4 upgrade of an outdated symfony 3. I removed all the bundle to have to correct file architecture but i probably messed something up.

Just doing bin/console in the command line I get this error :

```
The autoloader expected class "App\Controller\BrandAcadamyFeedback\FeedbackAnswerController" to be defined in file "/Users/username/www/myfolder/sf/vendor/composer/../../src/Controller/BrandAcadamyFeedback/FeedbackAnswerController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo in /Users/username/www/myfolder/sf/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/Users/username/www/myfolder/sf/config/services.yaml").
```

Here are my files :

Services.yaml

```
imports:
- { resource: security.yaml }

parameters:
   locale: 'en'

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true 
        public: false

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/*'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

FeedbackAnswerController.php

```
namespace App\Controller\BrandAcadamyFeedback;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Post;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;
use App\Controller\API\APIController;

/**
* Controller for Entity\BrandAcadamyFeedback\FeedbackAnswer.
*
* @View
* @Route("/api/feedback-answer")
*/
class FeedbackAnswerController extends APIController
{
}
```

Annotations.yaml

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

Composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

It's probably something easy but couldn't figure it out, nor find an answer online.

Any help would be highly appreciated. I hope I gave enough information.

Comment: Aren't `annotation.yml` and `services.yml` in the same dir ? Cause they don't point at the same directory for `controllers ressource`

Comment: They are not in the same dir : annotations.yaml is under config/routes/ and services.yaml is under config/

Comment: In your `service.yaml` you're just defining this `resource: '../src/Controller/*` but you're controller is in a sub directory. Shouldn't you do `resource: '../src/Controller/*/*` or something ?

Comment: I tried '../src/Controller/, '../src/Controller/*' and '../src/Controller/*/*' the issue is always the same.

Comment: Triple check your spelling though I suspect you already have.  I duplicated your controller and had the same error before realizing that I spelt Academy wrong.  Once the spelling was fixed then everything worked as expected.  If you are still stuck then make a new project and just get this controller to work.  You will probably discover the problem.  And the default resource: '../src/Controller' in services.yaml works just fine.

Comment: That was it, I must have been really tired to not notice that... AcadAmy... Sorry I made you lost your time and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Cerad comment I went and quadruple check the namespace for my controllers and there was indeed an error spell in the folder name of my app.

"App\Controller\BrandAcadamyFeedback\" should have been App\Controller\BrandAcademyFeedback\

Sorry.